# Getting object instance by string name in scala

Tags: reflection, scala, singleton

I need the object (or "singleton object" or "companion object"... anything but the class) defined by a string name.  In other words, if I have:

```
package myPackage
object myObject
```

...then is there anything like this:

```
GetSingletonObjectByName("myPackage.myObject") match {
  case instance: myPackage.myObject => "instance is what I wanted"
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Scala is still missing a reflection API. You can get the an instance of the companion object by loading the companion object class:

```
import scala.reflect._
def companion[T](implicit man: Manifest[T]) : T = 
  man.erasure.getField("MODULE$").get(man.erasure).asInstanceOf[T]


scala> companion[List$].make(3, "s")
res0: List[Any] = List(s, s, s)
```

To get the untyped companion object you can use the class directly:

```
import scala.reflect.Manifest
def companionObj[T](implicit man: Manifest[T]) = { 
  val c = Class.forName(man.erasure.getName + "$")
  c.getField("MODULE$").get(c)
}


scala> companionObj[List[Int]].asInstanceOf[List$].make(3, "s")
res0: List[Any] = List(s, s, s)
```

This depends on the way scala is mapped to java classes.

Comment: Holy cow.  Do you know if this syntax is a fixed part of the Scala spec (as fixed as anything else in the language, anyway)?  It seems like a bad idea to rely on this.  And since my goal was to make the code *clearer*...  Thank you!

Comment: As he mentioned, there is no reflection API in Scala yet, so whether this is covered by the Scala spec or not, this is the only way for you to do it.

I noticed this question / answer is over a year old, are there any news here?

Answer (score 57):

In scala 2.10 we can do like this

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe

val runtimeMirror = universe.runtimeMirror(getClass.getClassLoader)

val module = runtimeMirror.staticModule("package.ObjectName")

val obj = runtimeMirror.reflectModule(module)

println(obj.instance)
```

Answer (score 11):

Adjustment to Thomas Jung's answer above: you would do better to say companion[List.type] because a) this should be a stable way to refer to it, not dependant on the name mangling scheme and b) you get the unerased types.

```
def singleton[T](implicit man: reflect.Manifest[T]) = {
  val name = man.erasure.getName()
  assert(name endsWith "$", "Not an object: " + name)
  val clazz = java.lang.Class.forName(name)

  clazz.getField("MODULE$").get(clazz).asInstanceOf[T]
}  

scala> singleton[List.type].make(3, "a")                       
res0: List[java.lang.String] = List(a, a, a)
```

Comment: How is this better than just `List.make(3, "a")`? The OP wanted to get the object by string name

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I was looking for. It's certainly a hack, but less dirty than what I managed to come up with.

Answer (score 1):

Barring reflection tricks, you can't. Note, for instance, how the method `companion` is defined on Scala 2.8 collections -- it is there so an instance of a class can get the companion object, which is otherwise not possible.

Comment: Could you add a link to the source, please?

Comment: http://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/browser/scala/trunk/src/library/scala, though, hopefully, 2.8's Scaladoc 2 will soon contain links to the source, as already happens with 2.7.

Answer (score 0):

Scala 2:

```
          val runtimeMirror = universe.runtimeMirror(this.getClass.getClassLoader)

          val objectClass = Class.forName("org.test.MyObject$")
          val moduleSymbol = runtimeMirror.staticModule(objectClass.getName)
          val moduleMirror = runtimeMirror.reflectModule(moduleSymbol)
          val instance = moduleMirror.instance
```

Or just use Java API to get the value from the static field:

```
          val instance = objectClass.getField("MODULE$").get(null)
```

Mind the `$` in the object name.