# Unit Test controllers in Play 2 framework with Scala

Tags: scala, unit-testing, model-view-controller, playframework, playframework-2.0

The problem seems really simple in an MVC style where every layer is supposed to be separated. However, when you apply the recommended Play 2 coding style (according to "Play for Scala") then it becomes difficult to Unit test controllers by isolating them.

Here is the code proposed by the authors of "Play for Scala" for a simple controller :

```
Object product extends Controller {
  def list = Action { implicit request =>
    val products = Product.findAll
    Ok(views.html.products.list(products))
  }
}
```

How is it possible to mock the DAO "Product" in order to isolate it from the database, with this way of calling for data ?

```
val products = Product.findAll
```

Product is not injected it seems nor a simple variable of this object that you could mock.

Did I miss or misunderstood something ?
Is there any possibility to Unit test this ? Mocking or any other solution isolating the controller's method ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "default" coding style as advocated by Play is really bad. As you noticed, everything is an object, therefor it is very difficult to unit test components.

The solution is to use the `GlobalSettings` object to create controllers as classes instead of objects.

See http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaDependencyInjection to learn about how to control the creation of controllers (this allows you to declare them as classes, taking dependencies in their construtor) and http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaGlobal to use the various hooks (`onStart`, `onStop`, etc) to instantiate your resources.

With controllers declared as classes it is easy to unit tests them separately and mock their dependencies from different layers/modules.

Edit: Note that I do *not* recommend any DI framework like the Play documentation suggests. Seriously, just treat your `GlobalSettings` as a `main`, instantiate your components and be done with it. Don't try to add yet another useless dependency to Spring, Guice et al.

Comment: The Play default coding style might not be great, but instantiating your controllers at runtime (as opposed to compile time) like you are suggesting isn't great either. I cannot upvote this.

Comment: @DCKing And when would you instantiate your controllers? Before starting your app?

Comment: If you instantiate them as `object`s, they are instatiated before starting your app or you get a compile error. What you are suggesting  can lead to runtime errors.

Comment: 1) wrong: objects are instantiated when they are needed, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6249569/force-initialization-of-scala-singleton-object Play won't instantiate them until an incoming request needs them. 2) I suggested using the `onStart` hook to instantiate resources - including controllers. You can still create only one instance and return it to serve the appropriate requests.

Comment: Yes, `objects` are therefore instantiated whenever the `Routes` object is created. But their instantiation is guaranteed to succeed.

Comment: In my experience using old good constructors is less prone to runtime errors than any DI framework I've seen. +1 for recommending usage of constructors for DI.

Comment: @DCKing I invite you to try it and see for yourself that you are wrong. In both cases you get the same level of compile/runtime safety.  Plus, I do agree with @Ionut G. Stan, the cake pattern is effectively an anti-pattern as suggested many times by Odersky, Sabins and others. Play! mentions it only because the `GlobalSettings` was introduced recently, and it used to be the only way.

Comment: @vptheron `GlobalSettings` has been in Play 2.0 since the start and `getControllerInstance` since Play 2.1. It would be better to have a `controllers.scala` where you instantiate your controllers like `object ProductController extends ProductController(arguments)`. Then you 1) don't need to tinker with `GlobalSettings`, 2) can keep the traditional routes file syntax, and 3) have the Scala runtime instatiate your controllers instead of your own code.

Comment: `getControllerInstance` was added in 2.1 for a reason. Because people were complaining that the "everything is an object" design sucked. I think at some point one has to know when to let it go. Enjoy your cake pattern and the 5 or 6 classes/traits to maintain.

Comment: @vptheron There's really no reason for that hostility. Static initialization has advantages, and I'm pointing that out to you. I'm not a big fan of the cake pattern myself.

Answer (score 4):

The recommended way to increase the testability of your controllers is to use Scala-flavoured dependency injection. [Read up on the cake pattern](https://coderwall.com/p/t_rapw) for more information on how to do that.

In the case of your application, it could look like this.

```
// ProductController.scala
trait ProductController extends Controller {
  this: ProductComponent =>

  def list = Action { implicit request =>
    val products = Product.findAll
    Ok(views.html.products.list(products))
  }
}

// Somewhere else
trait ProductComponent {
   val products: ProductDao
}

trait AppProductComponent {
   val products = RealProductDao()
}

// controllers.scala
object ProductController extends ProductController with AppProductComponent

// MyTest.scala
trait TestProductComponent {
   val products = MockedProductDao()
}

val productController = new ProductController with TestProductComponent
// Test productcontroller here
```

Comment: Why is this downvoted? The cake pattern is even used in the documentation's pages on testing! http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaTestingWithSpecs2

Comment: I didn't downvote, but the cake (anti?)pattern is a contraption that doesn't really provide any benefit over constructor injection (opinions will vary, of course). Martin Odersky dropped it when writing the Dotty compiler: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/scala-user/n50RW4gQBS4/8vFeaC_caq0J

Comment: @IonuțG.Stan It's not really relevant what people's opinions are on the usefulness of the cake pattern: it doesn't change the fact that it is still recommended by the Play documentation and used successfully in many applications and by other people. This is *factually* the recommended way to do it. Anyway, thanks for pointing me to that, it's a good read!

Comment: I think it's relevant because their recommendation is an opinion as well, as long as alternatives are possible, like the one mentioned by @vptheron.