# Automatically initialize object in Scala

Tags: scala, annotations, scala-macros

If you run this simple code, you will see the following:

```
object A {
  println("from A")
  var x = 0
}

object B {
  println("from B")
  A.x = 1
}

object Test extends App {
  println(A.x)
}

// Result:
// from A
// 0
```

As you can guess, scala initialize objects lazily. Object B is not initialized and it works not as expected. My question here: what **tricks** can i use to initialize object B without accessing it ? The first trick i can use is extend object with some trait and use reflection to initialize object that extends specific trait. I think more elegant way is to annotate object with macro annotation:

```
@init
object B {
  println("from B")
  A.x = 1
}

class init extends StaticAnnotation {
  def macroTransform(annottees: Any*) = macro init.impl
}

object init {
  def impl(c: whitebox.Context)(annottees: c.Expr[Any]*): c.Expr[Any] = {
    import c.universe._

    // what should i do here ?
  }
}
```

But I little bit confused. How to invoke methods (in order to init) from annotated object in macro `impl` method ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Force initialization of Scala singleton object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6249569/force-initialization-of-scala-singleton-object)

Comment: Where would the generated code go? If inside `object B`, it's still not going to be called until `B` is accessed; if it creates a new `object`, _it_ will have to be accessed by the external code; and you can't modify existing `object`s outside the file in the macro.

Comment: "initialize object B without accessing it" - that's a contradiction. Accessing and initializing is the same thing. If in `object Test` you write `B`, you'll initialize/access it. But as you've noticed, initializing other objects from the body of another object is an anti-pattern. Simply don't do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found the solution:

**Usage:**

```
object A {
  println("from A")
  var x = 0
}

@init
object B {
  println("from B")
  A.x = 1
}

@init
object C {
  println("from C")
  A.x = 2
}

object Test extends App {
  init()
  println(A.x)
}
```

**Output:**

```
from B
from A
from C
2
```

**Macro implementation:**

```
class init extends StaticAnnotation {
  def macroTransform(annottees: Any*) = macro init.impl
}

object init {
  private val objFullNames = new mutable.MutableList[String]()

  def impl(c: whitebox.Context)(annottees: c.Expr[Any]*): c.Expr[Any] = {
    import c.universe._

    annottees.map(_.tree).toList match {
      case (obj: ModuleDef) :: Nil =>
        objFullNames += c.typecheck(obj).symbol.fullName
      case _ =>
        c.error(c.enclosingPosition, "@init annotation supports only objects")
    }

    annottees.head
  }

  def apply() = macro runImpl

  def runImpl(c: whitebox.Context)(): c.Expr[Any] = {
    import c.universe._
    val expr = objFullNames.map(name => q"${c.parse(name)}.##").toList
    val res = q"{..$expr}"
    c.Expr(res)
  }
}
```