# Scala: Getting companion objects to register themselves in repository object

Tags: scala

I have a bunch of singleton "worker" objects, and a central "repository" that is a thinly disguised map, mapping worker names to workers:

```
trait Worker { def work(): String }
object WorkerA extends Worker { [...] }
[...]
object WorkerX extends Worker  { [...] }
object Repository {
  private val repo: scala.collection.mutable.Map[String,Worker] = Map()
  def register(name:String,worker:Worker) = repo.put(name,worker)
}
```

I would really like the Repository to be automatically populated with all the workers at start of the program, so I tried something like this:

```
object WorkerA extends Worker {
  ... 
  println("Registering A")
  Repository.register("A",this)
}
```

but to my surprise "Registering A" was never printed (and the worker was not registered at the repository). I found out that this is because Scala is lazy about initializing companion objects.

So, is there a way to force non-lazy initialization, or any other way that I can do what I want in Scala (short of using reflection or keeping an explicit list of workers in the definition of Repository)?

Comment: Check this [DelayedInit approach](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6249569/force-initialization-of-scala-singleton-object)

Comment: You can define them as `val WorkerA = new Worker { ... }` so that they will be initialized eagerly.

Comment: There is no way to "force non-lazy initialization" for objects. The JVM would have to be "omniscient". Imagine you add another library/jar to your classpath containing more classes that inherit `Worker`, how would the system have the slightest knowledge of these and invoke their constructors? You would have to crawl the classpath and inspect all classes. I think @bali182 's answer is correct, you should pro-actively populate your map. Another option would be to have the repo provide an opaque key that the worker requires, that way at least you cannot invoke an unregistered worker.

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492184/how-do-you-find-all-subclasses-of-a-given-class-in-java

Answer (score 2):

I don't think registering themselves in a repository is the responsibility of the `Worker` constructor. If you have only objects, I'd do this (clearer for the reader too):

```
object Repository {
  val workers: Map[String, Worker] = Map(
    "a" -> WorkerA, // or whatever their names are
    "x" -> WorkerX
  )
}
```

If you want to do it dynamically too, then I'd hide the underlying map, like you did originally - since it has to be mutable - and do the registering after creation. Also I'd make the registering the responsibility of the creator.