# Retaining type information in List[Any]

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I'm using certain external library that has a method which is overloaded several times with different arguments, something like:

```
insertInto(index: Int, int: Int)
insertInto(index: Int, lng: Long)
insertInto(index: Int, dbl: Double)
insertInto(index: Int, str: String)
```

And a certain case class I'm using whose data I want to pass onto said methods, say:

```
case class C(str: String, lng: Long, dbl: Double, int: Int /* more values */)

val c = C("asd", 1, 1.1, 1)
```

Right now I'm using the library method like:

```
insertInto(1, c.int)
insertInto(2, c.lng)
insertInto(3, c.dbl)
insertInto(4, c.str)
//more insertions...
```

But since I'm always using the index of the value in the case classes I figured that maybe I could could save up on some lines of code (around 10) with something like the following:

```
c.productIterator.zipWithIndex.toList.foreach {
  case (idx, value) => insertInto(idx, value)
}
```

**But this doesn't work** because I'd be iterating a `List[Any]` and therefore the compiler complains that I'm not passing the correct argument type to `insertInto` since `Any` is not `String, Int, Long, Double, etc..`

What would be the correct way of handling this? Thanks in advance

Comment: why not just define `def store(intput: C) = { /*implement your logic once*/ }` You then only need to do this once and you will not be calling `insertInto` every time.

Comment: Thanks for your input @marios. Wouldnt the multiple `insertInto()`s be inside the `store()` method then? My goal is to compress several `insertInto()`s by iterating the case class values

Comment: You cannot ... the types of List[Any] can be checked again at only at Runtime. However, dew to JVMs type erasure, all overloaded methods above become indistinguishable at runtime. The types live only during compile time. So if you remove the types using productIterator, you can no longer invoke the overloaded methods.

Comment: You can probably do something more fancy using macros or shapeless, but do you really need to take this road? :)

Answer (score -1):

```
  case class A[T](t:T)(implicit tag: ClassManifest[T]){
    val newTag = tag
    override def toString= t+" "+tag.toString
  }
  case class C(xs:List[Any])
  val c=C(List(A("a"),A[Long](1), A[Double](1.1), A[Int](1)))

  c.xs.foreach(println)
```

Try this. I am using Scala 2.9.3. In newer versions, you can use TypeTag and ClassTag. Check [here](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/reflection/typetags-manifests.html)

So now you have the class type information. You can devise some mechanism to map class type value as string to `.class` instance and then use `asinstanceof` to cast it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer (it wasn't me who downvoted by the way). This would be nice but if i tried to use use `instanceOf[T]` with `T` being the *TypeTag* the compiler would still complain about it not being `String, Int, Double, etc` but of type `T`

Comment: check this out. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1913092/getting-object-instance-by-string-name-in-scala.  Once you have type T as string you can use that to instantiate and cast your objects

Comment: Interesting, thanks, I did check it out. I still fail to see how would i do that other than by using several  `if`s and explicitely doing many `asInstanceOf[Int]`,  `asInstanceOf[String]` and such